# Docusign Api: Why can't I select the template to send the envelope with?

Tags: rest, docusignapi

I have a problem sending envelopes with DocuSign. I specify the templateId that I want to use (lets say, template 2) with the envelope, but the recipient keeps getting template 1 instead of template 2 or template 3.

Here is my JSON object:

```
    {
  "emailSubject": "Test Email",
  "emailBlurb": "This is for testing docusign api",
  "templateId": "{2}",
  "templateRoles": [
    {
      "email": "email",
      "name": "Shawn Williams",
      "roleName": "Signee",
      "tabs": {
        "fullNameTabs": [
          {
            "tabLabel": "Name 67755b0d-2284-.....id",
            "value": "Shawn Williams"
          }
        ],
        "companyTabs": [
          {
            "tabLabel": "Company f9d5d265-9d97-....id",
            "value": "SDD"
          }
        ],
        "titleTabs": [
          {
            "tabLabel": "Title 35713ae4-3330-4....id",
            "value": "MR"
          }
        ],
        "ssnTabs": [
          {
            "tabLabel": "SSN",
            "value": "123456789"
          }
        ],
        "firstNameTabs": [
          {
            "tabLabel": "F_Name",
            "value": "Shawn"
          }
        ],
        "lastNameTabs": [
          {
            "tabLabel": "L_Name",
            "value": ""
          }
        ],
        "emailAddressTabs": [
          {
            "tabLabel": "Email",
            "value": "swi"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "transactionId": "test-2-id",
  "status": "sent"
}
```

I would really appreciate some help; I have been working on this for 3 days now.

Edit: I send a post to '/envelopes' and my account is in the demo stage right now in case that is important.

I'm using template Ids: 66b9f112-d135-4e74-9a30-1c0a2333ae5b, and cf5a9348-0d05-44ab-b0ac-8847303aa0ba. They are purely for testing  reasons and have different fields attached.

Comment: _recipient keeps getting template 1 instead of template 2 or template 3_ ... You are only specifying one template in your request, It should not reference any other templates. What is the difference between Template 1 , 2 & 3? What is the difference in behavior that you are getting? Please post your Template ID's.

Comment: Also can you try without the **transactionId** in your request

Comment: @CodingDawg  I'm trying to specify which template I want them to receive, not send multiple templates. Also I need transactionId to track the envelope when I get the callback.

Comment: I meant share your TemplateId's in the question so that I can look up the differences between them. What is the difference between Template 1 , 2 & 3? What is the difference in behavior that you are getting?

Comment: I try to send an envelope with template cf5a9348-0d05-44ab-b0ac-8847303aa0ba, but the recipient gets a document with template 66b9f112-d135-4e74-9a30-1c0a2333ae5b fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are specifying the **transactionId** in your [CreateEnvelope](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/) request. This is preventing from a new envelope being sent using the new template.

Remove the property  `"transactionId": "test-2-id"` and your envelope should be sent with the new template. Or use a new value for the transaction Id property for each envelope.

From [Documentation](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/#definitions--envelopeDefinition) : (expand the envelopeDefinition property)

> **transactionId** : Used to identify an envelope. The id is a sender-generated value and is valid in the DocuSign system for 7 days. *It is recommended that a transaction ID is used for offline signing to ensure that an envelope is not sent multiple times*. The transactionId property can be used determine an envelope's status (i.e. was it created or not) in cases where the internet connection was lost before the envelope status was returned.