# Envelope Created Each Time Signer Views Document

Tags: docusignapi

I am new to the DocuSign API.

We are using the SOAP API.

The issue we are running into is the client is using up envelopes faster than anticipated with a completion rate of only about 40%.

What appears to be happening is the user views the document to be signed, an envelope is generated and then the user chooses to not sign the document at that time.  When they return to the document, a new envelope is generated.  We retain the envelope ID in our database.  Is there a way I can retrieve and use the previously generated envelope instead of generating a new one each time the client views the document?  Please let me know the flow, API calls, links to relevant documentation, anything that would point me in the right direction.

Comment: I assume it isn't actually creating new envelopes. Have you logged into DocuSign and viewed the actual documents created? Are they being duplicated or is this just reminder emails?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the **TransactionId** in your [CreateEnvelope](https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/APIGuide.htm#Sending%20Group/Create%20and%20Send.htm) request and track the envelope so that it is not recreated.

> TransactionId: An optional element that can be used to identify an envelope. The id is a sender-generated value and is valid in the DocuSign system for 7 days.
>   This is typically used when calling SynchEnvelope. The transactionId can be used determine an envelope status (i.e. was created or not) for cases where an internet connection was lost before the envelope status could be returned.

Your application will have to determine, whether to pass a previous TransactionId or a new TransactionId based on the need to generate the new envelope.

Also see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43880557/1219543).